# Angular 4 application receiving ViewComponent ASP.Core server responses

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, single-page-application

I am trying to build a single-page application with an ASP.Core + Angular 4 stack. The server is supposed to provide view components, which will be rendered client-side and populated with additional data.

The best way to create components would be utilising ViewComponent mechanic on the server, which allows me to effectively create HTML layouts and populate my HTML components with data from DB. Alas, I have not yet found a way to transfer the data to my Angular 4 client app. The ViewComponents are not static resources, meaning I (most likely) can't transfer it as JSON-data, and even if I could, I'd have to teach my client how to unwrap it back into html, which would increase the load on the client.

I have confirmed that JQuery calls can be made to receive IViewComponentResult responses, but I am yet to find a way on how to achieve same results in an Angular component. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually with this stack you use `.NET Core` as the backend meaning you use it to write the `Web API` code which interacts with the database. The `Angular` side of things would have `services` which call the `Web API` via `http` methods and present/manipulate the data in `component.html/.css/.ts` files.

You can read through a guide such as [this](https://medium.com/@levifuller/building-an-angular-application-with-asp-net-core-in-visual-studio-2017-visualized-f4b163830eaa) to get an idea of the structure and flow of the stack. Everything you mentioned in your 2nd paragraph can be achieved through this architecture without the worry of transferring `ViewComponents`.

Comment: This is indeed a viable solution, but there are two cons:
1) This makes the client bigger and heavier
2) We'd have to write Typescript instead of C#, which we prefer.
Our small team agrees this would be what we'll most likely choose, but if there's a way to write layout and store it server-side, we'd prefer that.

Comment: If that is the case why not just write web app in .NET Core MVC

Comment: Our goal is to deliver a single-page application, which would be incredibly harder to maintain with regular JS/JQuery/AJAX stack, which is why Angular was brought up.
Then again, I understand your reasoning and some things were indeed cleared up for me. I'll mark your answer as the accepted for now.